# Creating a site badge or widget in rails: Problem calling the second script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing my best to create a site badge or widget for [my site](http://goldhat.org), which is a rails site.

Essentially it's a site where users post content that they've created and other who like that content can make a donation to express their appreciation for it.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843779/article-stats-widget-in-rails) a while back about how to create a widget, but that was before I had done any real study of Javascript.

The first script (in localhost:3000/javascripts/widget.js) worked fine I think:

```
    var Widget = 
{
    init:function()
    {
        var loc = window.location;
        var title = document.title;
        var href = 'http://localhost:3000/donations/new.js?url=' + encodeURIComponent(loc);

        href = href + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = href;
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);

    }
};
Widget.init();
```

(The reason why I entitled it new.js was because that's where all the statistics for the link are displayed on the main site)
To test this script I made a simple HTML file to call it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Widget</title>
        <script src="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Widget</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the above script runs I checked firebug and sure enough it calls the second script:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/donations/new.js?url=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2Fgoldhat_production%2Ftest_widget.html&amp;title=Test%20Widget" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally I created a new.js.erb file with the following script just to make sure that it was being called:

```
var Stats =
{
    init: function()
    {
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
};
Stats.init();
```

And in the donations controller I added the following code to the "new" action:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
end
```

So I gave it a whirl and I don't get a Hello World alert when I refresh the page but when I get what is actually being called I get this error (truncated):

```
 26<h1>
27 ActionController::MethodNotAllowed
28
29</h1>
30<pre>Only put requests are allowed.</pre>
31
32
33
34<p><code>RAILS_ROOT: c:/goldhat_production</code></p>
35
36<div id="traces">
```

There seems to be a lot of places where I could go wrong with this, I'm not sure where, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes.rb file is only allowing `put` requests to your `new` action.  New should allow get if you are using `map.resources`, but it appears you are not using that functionality.

I see you have three options:

1)  If you are going to be using rjs, then move the javascript call to a different method that isn't already being used and set up the route to that action if necessary.

```
map.connect '/donations/[action_name]', :controller => 'donations', :action => '[action_name]', :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

2)  If you are not going to be using rjs, just move it to static resources.  Just move the file to your `/public/javascripts` directory and link to it from there.

3)  allow `get` requests to your `new` method, by adding this to your routes.rb.  This might be just allowing the action in your existing route statement, depending on what is already there.

```
map.connect '/donations/new', :controller => :donations, :action => :new, :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

I would personally go with option 1 or 2, just because I don't see the relationship to "new", but I likely don't see the full picture.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with my routes. I'll have to try this out and let you know.

Comment: Hi Geoff, your solution worked.

I messed around with the routes and decided it was best to have my own widget controller, just so that it doesn't interfere with other functionality.

In the end I had a "map.resources :widget" line in my routes and an index.js.erb file with the hello world code in it. What a relief it was to see the alert pop up on one of my other sites!

Thanks a lot!